# Executing a stored proc inside a script file using the sqlcmd -i

Tags: sql, sqlcmd

Need some help with script files.
I have an SQL script file in the following format:

```
Begin tran

insert..

select..

update..

Commit
exec linked_server.db1.dbo.storedproc1
```

I am calling the above script file from within a .js file in the following manner:

```
var sCommand = "sqlcmd -i C:\\scriptfile1"

var WshShell = new ActiveXObject("WScript.Shell");

var oExec = WshShell.Exec(sCommand);
```

When I run the .js file, the code between tran-commit gets executed but the storeproc1 is never called. I know for sure that the storedproc1 is not called because it has a list of insert statements that never shows up in the table.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried running the `exec storedproc1` alone? Maybe it throws an error.

Also you can try adding `go` like this:

```
commit
go
exec storedproc1
```

You can try this in the management studio first. After you are sure it works in the management studio, you can go on running it through sqlcmd.

Edit: next you can check the permission of the user running the script, whether it is allowed to run stored procedure.

Comment: The "go" doesnt work. The stored proc throws no errors and is running fine.

Comment: How about the permission of the user running the script?

Comment: Ok. My bad! The "stored proc 1" was not running on that server but on a different linked server. Although I am using the linked server name correctly, it doesnt execute. Connecting ":connect" to that server and executing "stored proc 1" worked fine.